# How to use material symbols in react native app?

Tags: react-native

https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/material_symbols

I was following this developer guide and there is instructions for iOS and android apps but none for react native. I was wondering if there's any npm packages that can render material symbols for react. Only way i know is to download the svgs and serve from an assets folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [react-native-vector-icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons) to import your font and [icoMoon](https://icomoon.io/) to define the name of each icon.

See the documentation here: [React Native Vector Icons - Custom Fonts](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#createiconsetfromicomoonconfig-fontfamily-fontfile)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this [material-symbols](https://github.com/marella/material-symbols) library.

I ran `npm install @material-symbols/svg-400@latest` and just imported from the module:

`import ReleaseAlertOutlined from '@material-symbols/svg-400/outlined/release_alert.svg'`

This should save you from having to manually download icons into an assets folder and instead just pull using the library.